# Ограничение доступа к API сайта

Tags: безопасность

предположим, есть сервис, который по get запросу на страницу `/sms.php` отправляет смс сообщение. Параметры сообщения передаются как get-параметры. но нужно ограничить доступ к этому api. вопрос - насколько безопасен и правилен будет подход, когда одним из get-параметров передается пароль (`/sms.php?pass=12345`), который знают нужные клиенты и сервер. на сервере же просто проверяем, равен ли `$_GET['pass']` 12345...Или этот способ такого ограничения доступа к api уязвим? Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Отправку SMS все же лучше делать по POST-запросу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет, это не правильно и не безопасно. Вот несколько соображений по поводу аутентификации запросов к API.

То, что идет по HTTP **без шифрования** по-определению не безопасно, поскольку подвержено атаке типа [Man in the middle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Если злоумышленник реализует атаку этого типа, то ваш клиент рано или поздно потеряет свой пароль (токен, cookie, ...) для доступа к API. Единственный способ защиты (кроме шифрования): не передавать пароль по сети. Вообще. Существуют, например, методы оффлайн генерации одноразового токена/пароля при помощи физических устройств, хотя не думаю, что в вашем случае это применимо.

Из того, что я знаю, при отсутствии шифрования можно использовать только [дайджест-аутентификацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), (Digest Authentication). Однако нужно понимать, что пароль (на основе которого подсчитывается контрольная сумма сообщения) должен быть передан клиенту по **защищенному каналу**. Кроме того, нужно предпринимать определенные шаги к защите от атак на повторение сообщений. Подробнее описывать не буду, тема довольно обширная.

Что касается передачи токена(пароля) через GET параметр, то это плохая идея даже если используется протокол HTTPS. С очень большой долей вероятности, все **запросы к серверу логируются**. Apache, например, по-умолчанию записывает в лог и все GET параметры. В принципе, логи должны надежно храниться на сервере, но я бы не стал надеяться, что никто не сможет получить к ним доступ. Все-таки логи охраняются с существенно меньшей паранойей чем доступы, например, к базе данных. По этому лучше (и идеологически правильнее) использовать POST запросы.

Если используется шифрование, то вы можете использовать один из следующих методов аутентификации:

1. Передавать пароль/токен в теле POST запроса
2. Использовать [базовую аутентификацию](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (Basic Authentication)
3. [Дайджест-аутентификацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), (Digest Authentication)
4. Сначала генерировать для пользователя временный токен, а уже потом использовать его для аутентификации
5. Использовать cookie и механизм сессий (не очень в хорошо для API, но иногда удобно)

Список выше не претендует на полноту, но это самые очевидные и часто используемые варианты аутентификации.