# Защита мобильного приложения

Tags: php, mysql, безопасность, сеть

Есть некое мобильное приложение, которое отсылает GET-запрос на сервер, где тот в свою очередь обрабатывается PHP, связывается с БД и выдает результат в Json.

Что такое PHP, XSS инъекции, я понял, но как **реализовать защиту от ботов**, чтобы не было, к примеру, добавление в БД ненужной информации, и в больших объемах? Стоит ли вообще переживать о ботах, если никакого web-интерфейса для PHP, БД нет?

Comment: Может быть полезно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455204/182771

Comment: Если нет веб-интерфейса, то куда вы отсылаете запрос? Обычно против ботов используют капчу.

Comment: @Darth, web-интерфес нужен далеко не всегда. Существует возможность использовать некий API (машинный) на сервере вместе с приложением.

Comment: а api это не интерфейс? по моему буква i как раз это слово за собой прячет

Answer (score 1):

Об этом надо было заранее думать и например систему токенов внедрить для аутентификации. То есть каждое приложение проходит авторизацию, получает ключ доступа и при каждом запросе его посылает. Без аутентификации ваш сервер открыт всем, и если вы будете смотреть и анализировать логи запросов к серверу, то увидите много интересного и не только на 80 порт.

Если у вас приложение не с финансами работает, то не так страшно. Сейчас куда чаще используются `DDoS` атаки от которых по моему мнению небольшому проекту сложнее защитится.

Не стоит так же забывать про `HTTPS`, когда разрабатываете мобильные приложения.

### UPD

Реализовать можно например через статичный ключ, но для этого обязательно протокол `HTTPS` использовать, что бы никто его не получил простым снифом трафика.

Но лучше динамический токен, например полученный при открытии приложения. Или выдавать на какое-то время и при окончании срока действия проходит повторную авторизацию. Токен можно в заголовках передавать, а можно и в параметрах запросов.

Comment: Об этом надо было заранее думать и например систему токенов внедрить для аутентификации - Как это реализуется? Т.е. У приложения есть ключ который выдан сервером. и этот ключ каждый раз передается в GET запросе?

Comment: @StasP. обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

ВВеди статистику. К примеру твое приложение где то скачивают добавляешь ип в базу. потом когда его запускают оно куда то отстукивает в php скрипт. в php - сделай проверку есть ли ип в базе который скачал приложение. Если ip нету, тогда это либо бот, либо кто то как то коряво лезет к тебе для таких можно добавить блэк лист ипов. Для чистоты статистики ботов лучше фильтровать, их развелось много.

Comment: Супер, а если у меня динамический ip, то у меня хреновая жизнь начнется с таким приложением. гениально!)

Comment: ну так введи black и white листы масок ip
127.0.*.* либо ключ в приложении

Answer (score 0):

1. Создать бот без документации вашего API очень сложно.
2. Если сниверить канал вашего мобильного приложения с сервером, не всегда можно получить полный API

Я в таких случаях делал следующее.

1. В сервере и в приложении делал "вшитую шифрованию". То есть все данные между приложением и сервером шифруются из обоих сторон. - Это помогает при защите sniffering
2. Свой алгоритм шифрования можно вложить внутри SSL (https) канала. - Это защитит Вас от чтения данных со стороны провайдера
3. При каждом запросе серверу, если у вас данные идет последовательно, менять ключ сессии (token) что бы ваши запросы не смогли дублировать. - Обычно что бы создать помеху, делают копию пакета отправленного от мобильного к серверу и этот пакет отправляют несколько раз. Так сервер будет на пустую работать с данными. Если будете часто менять ключ (token), тогда повторный запрос не будет обрабатываться.
4. Использовать ЭЦП или хеширования или CRC (ЭЦП - Электронный цифровой подпись. Это делается, что бы никто не изменял целостьность пакета (запроса). Создается хеш значения из данных и добавляется в конец запроса. Сервер проверяет этот хеш, тоже методом хеширование отправленных данных)

Comment: При использовании ssl, пункт 1 не имеет смысла. совсем.

Comment: При использовании ssl, пункт 4 не имеет смысла

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Он имеет, смысл настояшее время, так как уже очень много методов есть, подмены ssl сертификатов. к примеру http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/88671/ http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/88717/

Comment: А еще можно в браузере тыкать "добавить исключение" каждый раз, когда всплывает окошко о кривом сертификате. Но это вовсе не означает, что ssl вдруг перестал работать. Если у разработчика есть контроль и над сервером и над мобильным приложением, то говорить о потенциальной возможности подмены сертификата бессмысленно. В приложении всегда можно проверить, что за сертификат использует сервер и прекратить взаимодействие при любых подозрениях

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вы правы, что если есть ssl то 1 и 4 можно не делать, но сейчас я не доверяю ssl на 100%, так как он тоже уже увезим, http://www.securitylab.ru/analytics/365717.php , лучше самому предохроняться

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вы правы, если приложение может проверять сертификат своего сервера, тогда я ЗА ВАС !!! Это поможет на 100%

Comment: Ссылка, на статью о уязвимости 2008 года - это сильно.